# tmux is showing zsh for vim with `pane_current_command`

Tags: bash, vim, tmux

For some reason Tmux is showing `zsh` when it should be showing `vim` for the output of `#{pane_current_command}`, this is screwing up my vim aware pane moving commands in tmux which rely on it working correctly:

```
# vim aware commands
# pane/split switching
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L" #left
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D" #down
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U" #up
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R" #right
bind -n C-\ run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\\') || tmux select-pane -l" #next
# pane/split creation
bind | run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-w && tmux send-keys v) || tmux split-window -h" #verticle
bind - run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-w && tmux send-keys s) || tmux split-window -v" #horizontal
# pane/split close
bind x run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-w && tmux send-keys q) || tmux kill-pane "
```

I'm starting vim via an alias:

```
alias vim='rbenv only -r 2.3.5 -c "/usr/local/bin/vim" $@'
```

it is indeed the alias the causing the issue, How do I fix this, is there any way to set the name of the current process?

I found `jobs -Z` but that doesn't seem to work for an alias.

Comment: Not sure it can help, but I had a similar problem with `mutt` a few days ago, and posted about it [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13933/11125).

Comment: I'm just guessing but I imagine tmux just looks up the immediate child process with `ps` or by looking at `/proc` files (in your case the child is `zsh` and `vim` is a "grandchild" process) and there's nothing you'll be able to do to change that short of hacking tmux code (or, in this example, invoking `vim` directly, not through intermediate shell). Or write/find code that let's you customize process name from the process (I know it's possible) and wrap your zsh/vim invocation in that. (!!)

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming `rbenv` launches a subshell within which your command runs. That would explain the behavior you're seeing. Things might be better if instead it did `exec`.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's pretty much it as well, any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after seeing the comment left by @B-Layer I created a simple bash function to replace the alias I was using that allows me to have my cake and eat it!

The function:

```
function vim()
{
    cmd="exec /usr/local/bin/vim $@"
    rbenv only -r $GLOBAL_RUB_VERSION -c "$cmd";
}
```

Now it allows me to start vim using rbenv only so it always starts with the same version of ruby that vim was compiled against. Now (the reason for this song and dance) YouCompleteMe won't ever complain/crash because I switched ruby versions.